# SQL many-to-many

Tags: sql, primary-key, composite-primary-key, erd

[image: entity relationship diagram]

I need to build a simple forum (message board) as a school project. But I came across one problem. In the img above there are 2 tables: `post` and `category`, which have many-to-many relationship. I made a bridge table, which stores the `postKey` and `categoryKey`. Is it a bad practice to create a composite primary key from those 2 keys, or I need something like `postCategoryKey`? And what else should I improve?

Answer (score 1):

On my opinion, there is no need for PostCategoryKey, due to it's only a relationship table and you won't accés it by postCategoryKey. 
I would create the PK using the 2 others FK (postKey and categoryKey).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

It depends, if you plan later on to add some extra metadata to `postCategoryKey` in a separate table, then it makes sense.

In your case - I'd go with a composite primary key and get rid of `postCategoryKey`

Answer (score 1):

You will have to make `postKey` and `categoryKey` not null and create a unique constraint on them anyway. That makes them a key for the table, no matter whether you call this the "primary key" or not.

So, there are three options:

1. Leave this as described with `NOT NULL` and the unique constraint.
2. Declare the two columns the table's primary key.
3. Create an additional column `postCategoryKey` and make this the primary key.

The decision doesn't really matter. Some companies have a database style convention. In that case it's easy; just follow the company rules. Some people want every table to have a single-column primary key. If so, add that PK column. Some people want bridge tables to have a composite primary key to imediately show what identifies a row. My personal preference is the latter, but any method is as good as the other actually. Just stay consistent in your database.